# How good is the performance of numpy.asarray() on typed MemoryView objects?

Tags: python, numpy, cython

Let's say I have following Cython code:

```
cimport cython
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np

cdef np.int64_t[:] view = np.zeros(1000, dtype=np.int64)
array = np.asarray(view)
```

What does `np.asarray()` do under the hood and how fast is it? Is the speed of this operation dependent on the size of the array? Is it generally a good idea to avoid such cases by keeping the original `ndarray` object from the beginning?

Comment: Please don't ask us for performance data that you can (and should) examine for yourself.  Whenever possible, *test it* before you post here.  "Is it generally a good idea" is an opinionated question (i.e. off-topic), and depends on your application.  Does your program run faster if you keep the array?  Is it easier to maintain?  What is your evaluation of "good idea"?  Until you've defined your value system, this is guesswork for us.

Comment: Provided it's a regular memoryview (not something unusual like an indirect memoryview) then it doesn't make a copy and just references the original object. You're probably still better measuring it, but it should be relatively OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I benchmarked `asarray()` now:

`asarray_benchmark.pyx`:

```py
cimport cython
cimport numpy as np

import numpy as np


ctypedef np.int32_t int32


def no_op(int32[:] a):
    pass

def as_array(int32[:] a):
    np.asarray(a)
```

`main.py`:

```py
from asarray_benchmark import no_op, as_array

import time
N = 1_000_000
now = time.time_ns()
array = np.zeros(100_000_000, dtype=np.int32)
for _ in range(N):
    no_op(array)
print(f"noop:    {(time.time_ns() - now) / N :>12.3f} ns")
for _ in range(N):
    as_array(array)
print(f"asarray: {(time.time_ns() - now) / N :>12.3f} ns")
```

Result:

```
noop:         317.934 ns
asarray:     1498.773 ns
```

It seems that `np.asarray()` takes ~1 μs on my notebook to run. This seems to be independent of array shape and size, indicating that no actual data is copied.